# How do I disable CSS or make my own CSS style for a specific website in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, styles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change default CSS of Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/52967/change-default-css-of-google-chrome)

Hello!

I often have to view a website, that has a terrible fonts and formatting, but I really need the info from there. So, I want to ask: is  there a way to change the CSS styles for the specific site, of disable CSS at all? I know, that this function is in Opera, but does Chrome have one?

I am using:

[image: google chrome]

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a duplicate! Queation in the link asks how to change the CSS for all sites, but this one asks about the specific site.

Answer (score 1):

[Web Developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) can change a website's CSS content.

I'm not sure about making it pseduo-permanent though.