# How can I customize the appearance of web sites in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change default CSS of Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/52967/change-default-css-of-google-chrome)
>   [How do I disable CSS or make my own CSS style for a specific website in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/266816/how-do-i-disable-css-or-make-my-own-css-style-for-a-specific-website-in-google-ch)

Web sites like Wikipedia that extend to the full width of the available screen are very annoying when used with a big monitor.

How can I customize their appearance (for example, by injecting some CSS) in Chrome?

Comment: Fun, fixed width sites used to make me feel like wasting money for having a wide enough monitor. But monitors are getting really too wide nowadays.

Comment: None of those marked as a duplicate answer this question. The "default CSS" is not a specific site but browser wide. The second link is marked as a duplicate of the first and was not given any useful answers.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome supports greasemonkey style user scripts by default. Read this for more info - http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts

Comment: There are also variants, for chrome, Tampermonkey and Violent monkey, they have good score on the chrome addon site.